# Averaging numbers comes out incorect

Tags: java

I have tried looking this up on here and still haven't found the exact solution that I am looking for. The math keeps coming out incorrectly.

```
       //Local Constants
       int count = 0;          //Used to track the number of grades entered by the user

       //Local Variables
       double currentGrade = 0;   //User's current grade inputed
       double numberGrades;       //Total number of grades to be entered
       double totalGrade = 0;     //Total of all grades
       double gradeAverage;       //Average of all grades

       //Main Function
      //Ask the user for the amount of grades they would like to enter
       System.out.print ("How many grades would you like to enter? ");
       numberGrades = scan.nextInt();

      //If the user asks to enter 0 numbers, output an error
       while (numberGrades <= 0){
           System.out.print ("Please enter a valid number! ");
         numberGrades = scan.nextInt();
       }
      //Add the grades together as they are input by the user
        while (count < numberGrades){
          totalGrade += currentGrade;
          System.out.print ("Please enter your next grade: ");
          currentGrade = scan.nextInt();
        count++;
        }
      //Calculate and output the average to the user
        gradeAverage = (totalGrade / numberGrades);
        System.out.print ("\n");
        System.out.print ("The average of all grades is: " + gradeAverage); 
  }
```

}

Thought this was fixed, but when I run it I'm still getting the same issue. The example I tried was to enter 3 numbers, each was 50. The average ended up being 33.0. I've run the debugger and it keeps giving me errors once the first number is entered. count, totalGrade and currentGrade all show as errors. No clue how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: Just debug your code then you'll may notice why your programm doesn't actually care about your last input.

Comment: @JoeBurkhart two things: 1) you're missing out one of the grades (the last one); 2) you're using integer division.

Comment: @AndyTurner I think you tagged the wrong Joe, mate.

Comment: @JoeC indeed! Retagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the sum before getting the input. You should do it after that.

Replace your `while` loop with following change:

```
        while (count < numberGrades){

          System.out.print ("Please enter your next grade: ");
          currentGrade = scan.nextInt();
          totalGrade += currentGrade;
        count++;
        }
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you. It sucks when it's something that simple that I just completely overlook after staring at the code for hours trying to move everything else around.